# How to select the 5 most recent records in a table from a SQLite database

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQLite database table schema called `Bans` like this.

```
| Name | Ban Reason |
| Noah | Swearing   |
| Liam | Toxicity   |
| Josh | Cheating   |
```

Such simple data continues for about another 20 rows. Naturally, the latest entries are at the top. In this case, the entry containing `Noah` would be the most recent addition to the table.

I want to retrieve the Top 5 most recent results. How can I do this using SQLite? I am vaguely aware that `LIMIT` should be used, but I cannot get it to work properly. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a tailored toy database (in the shape of a few lines of `create table ...` and `insert ...`) and the desired output, i.e. a [mre]. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SQLITE:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table 
LIMIT 5;
```

[Here is a DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/ff0ed/2)

Depending on what you think when you say latest 5 you can add

```
ORDER BY your_column DESC
```

or

```
ORDER BY your_column ASC
```

between `FROM` clause and `LIMIT` keyword.

But as I see your query uses a little bit different logic and select all that is not in top 5 so I have simulated that like this in SQLite:

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table 
where id not in 
(select id from your_table
LIMIT (SELECT COUNT(*) - 5 FROM your_table));
```

[Here is a DEMO for that EXAMPLE.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/ff0ed/5)

Comment: Oh, I wanted to select the 5 most recent ones from my query, not everything BUT the latest 5. It looks like my own query was wrong. So for SQLite, I would just do `SELECT * FROM tablename LIMIT 5 ORDER BY rowid DESC`?

Comment: No, sorry, `SELECT * 
FROM tablename 
order by row_id desc
LIMIT 5;`

Comment: @MatthewTrip never use LIMIT without ORDER BY.

Comment: @VBoka there's an issue. I assign a variable to my SQL command execution but it's a string that only return the latest record, not the latest 5. I'm using ExecuteScalar()

Comment: You are using that from where ? I do not know about ExecuteScalar() but I can see here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=netframework-4.8 this: "The first column of the first row in the result set, or a null reference". So I believe that this ExecuteScalar() will return only first row of your query so that would be the last row_id .

Comment: @MatthewTrip I suggest to you to open a new question. Before that it would be nice to accept this answer and vote up for it because it is a correct answer for this question. Thanks!

Comment: I should've used ExecuteReader, not  Scalar. Thanks for all your help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the rows with the top 5 [`rowid`](https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html)s you can do it with an `ORDER BY` clause and `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename
ORDER BY rowid DESC
LIMIT 5
```

but the correct way to define *latest* is by using a column like a `created_date`.